# Possibility to Loop with multiple read from HashInput in Talend

Tags: loops, recursion, talend

I want to build a Loop and execute a block multiple times. tLoop1 would be generating rows and tMap1 would be executed tLoop1(times) . I want to reiterate over a set of datarows until all have been processed. I'm aware that it doesn't work with tHashInput2 connected to tHashInput1, since there isn't a possibility to initialise it beforehand.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand how it all links together. Could you provide a screenshot instead of your ASCII diagram?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not directly use tRowGenerator_1 and tOracleInput_1 as inputs for the tMap?